# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_psutil_osx'

Tags: python, apple-m1, psutil

When I wanted to import '_psutil_osx' ，Error happend.

This is the clause

```
import _psutil_osx
```

and the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_psutil_osx'
```

And I confirmed that I have installed psutil, that's the result of `pip list`

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.1.2
psutil     5.9.5
PyGreSQL   5.2.4
PyYAML     6.0
setuptools 67.6.1
six        1.16.0
wheel      0.40.0`
```

ps: I runned this on Apple Silicon (M1)

I want to import `_psutil_osx` success

Comment: py -m pip install --no-binary :all: psutil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_psutil_osx` is a submodule of `psutil` so try

```
import psutil._psutil_osx
```

or

```
from psutil import _psutil_osx
```